# How to add type-writer effect when adding text to QTextEdit in PyQt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a string and a QTextEdit. Basically, when the user clicks the mouse button, I want to add the string to the QTextEdit, but I want it to print with a "slow/type-writer" effect, so every second the next letter in the string is appended to the text edit until the end of the string.

I think I could maybe use QThread for this, but I am not quite sure how to go about it. I've only just started learning about threads and processes in school. I tried using QThread as shown below, but the program became unresponsive/crashed.

```
text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
string = "This is the sentence I want to display."

thread = QtCore.QThread()
thread.start()

for c in string:
  text_edit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
  text_edit.append(c)
  thread.sleep(1)

thread.quit()
```

Edit:

```
text_edit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
string = "This is the sentence I want to display."

timer = QtCore.QTimer()

for c in string:
  text_edit.moveCursor(QtGui.QTextCursor.End)
  text_edit.append(c)
  timer.start(1000)
  while timer.isActive():
      # something?
  timer.stop()
```

Comment: You certainly don't need threads for that, as you could just use [QTimer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Also, threading would be wrong, as UI elements are not thread safe and should ***NEVER*** be directly accessed by external threads. Besides, your code doesn't make a lot sense: `sleep` is a static function that "blocks" the *current* thread (you'll have the same result by using `QThread.sleep(1)` and that `thread` object is useless). The real question is: are you **really** sure about this? Did you consider what would happen if the user does something while the code is still "typing"?

Comment: Suppose that I click on that QTextEdit and it starts typing a *long* phrase, then I click it again in the meantime. What should happen then? Even worse, what if I use the keyboard while the code is still processing the "typed" text, for instance by pressing other letters, Backspace or Delete, or even using clipboard shortcuts. And what if the "typed" text is too long and I clicked the widget by mistake: how could I cancel or undo the operation? Should I always wait for that operation to finish? I understand your "fancy" purpose, but do you realize the intricacies and issues of it?

Comment: @musicamante Yes, these concerns make sense. My idea was that the only user input the QTextEdit is dependent on is when the user presses the mouse button. If the user presses the mouse key while the "typed" text is still being added to the QTextEdit, then the slow printing would cease and the string would be added to to the QTextEdit in one go. My reasoning for using QThread.sleep() was because when you want to do the same thing printing to the terminal, the examples used time.sleep(), so I thought it would have the same effect. Would the edit to the post be more "correct" if using QTimer?

Comment: Using a terminal is not exactly the same: it depends on how the program is implemented. UI toolkits like Qt use event loops and Python prevents real concurrency (at least, in the same process). That said, as you also point out, your attempt shows important issues with user interaction. As a user, while the first "fancy typing animation" impression may seem "cool", I would eventually find it annoying and quite useless. The important thing to consider about UX is: does it improve the usage of the program to the user? Does *seeing* that "typing" really add something useful to their interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are better off using `QTimer`, than `QThread`.  You can use the class methods to set a `singleShot` timer for some number of milliseconds in between appending each character onto the existing message. You can fire the timer inside of a method that continues to call itself until it has completely entered the message text.

For Example:

```
...
...

TEXT = "Some long message that will be typed out one character at a time."

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.button = QPushButton("Click Me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.insert_phrase_char)
        self.text_phrase = list(TEXT)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def insert_phrase_char(self):
        if len(self.text_phrase) > 0:
            cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
            next_char = self.text_phrase.pop(0)
            cursor.insertText(next_char)
            QTimer.singleShot(300, self.insert_phrase_char)


app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]